# How to uncheck a check boxes in laravel collectives

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to uncheck a checkbox in laravel collectives. Is it possible?

```
{{Form::checkbox('name','',['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}
```

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are offset. You are passing the array as the 'checked' parameter, which will always cause it to be checked.

`{{Form::checkbox('name', 'value', 'checked', ['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}`